# fast ordered sort (and extract from) tuple based on list

Tags: python, sorting

I am a python newbie and I have been trying to sort (and extract) values from a tuple based on values on a list, but so far, my code seems really slow.

So, I have a list like so:

```
x = ["d5b44796d43c4bf5a0f252aeb49738f5", "04d0e11f8ceb4b128fa723181369ba1a", "6244dd8bfee44a61800a25d9f2e6f743", "662ae26640a44a37816daa6e85ef4972", "7d5e1f59f7984495877a059bea643954"]
```

the, I have a tuple like so:

```
y = [(31, u'dir/04d0e11f8ceb4b128fa723181369ba1a.mov'), (32, u'dir/d5b44796d43c4bf5a0f252aeb49738f5.pdf'), (66, u'dir/6244dd8bfee44a61800a25d9f2e6f743.jpg'), (34, u'dir/662ae26640a44a37816daa6e85ef4972.doc'), (33, u'dir/7d5e1f59f7984495877a059bea643954.ppt')]
```

I would like to get the `id` from `y` if the element in `x` is present in `y[i][1]`. So, something like this:

```
id_list=[]
for i in x:
    for j in y:
        if i in j[1]:
            try:
                id_list.append(j[0])
            except:
                pass
            break
        else:
            pass
```

I get:

```
id_list = [32, 31, 66, 34, 33]
```

Also, the result set has to maintain the order in `x`.
The above loop does this.

The problem is that the above code is very slow (ashamed of it!) - my `x` is in 1000's and so is `y`.

So I guess my question is if there a better way to write the above code? I was thinking iterators here but was not entirely sure how to write one in this case.

Comment: Will there be duplicates in the names in the tuples? For example, `04d0e11f8ceb4b128fa723181369ba1a.mov` and `04d0e11f8ceb4b128fa723181369ba1a.jpg` can occur?

Comment: no.. there will not be any duplicates...

Comment: Why don't you preprocess and create a dictionary?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id_list = [j[0] for j in sorted(y, key=lambda e: x.index(e[1].split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]))]
```

This can be improved if x was a `dict` since lookup will be faster, so we'll use `OrderedDict` to maintain the order:

```
import collections
from os.path import basename, splitext

x = collections.OrderedDict((e, i) for i, e in enumerate(x))

id_list = [j[0] for j in sorted(y, key=lambda e: x[splitext(basename(e[1]))[0]])]
```

Comment: Is your `OrderedDict` example complete? `x = collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(x)` does not make a lot of sense to me?

Comment: I think I got you wrong, you wish to sort `y` based on the order of `x`?

Comment: Yea, I need the `ids` from `y `based on the order of `x` if that makes sense.

Comment: hmm.. when I use your code I get `ValueError: [u'dir', u'04d0e11f8ceb4b128fa723181369ba1a.mov'] is not in list`

Comment: yes it works now! do you mind explaining what the `[:-4]` is doing here?

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much for this. To make it more generic, I have changed the `[-4]` to: `.split(".")[0]` to take into account extensions more than 3 char long.

Comment: @AJW broke it down for you in the answer. `[:-4]` slices the string from 0 to last character before the last 4.

Comment: Thanks again @Sir_FZ - accepted your answer. Thanks again for the detailed explanation.

Comment: use `[:-4]` may not be a good idea, what if we have a `dir/04d0e11f8ceb4b128fa723181369ba1a.rmvb`? I'd suggest using `os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(thefilepath))[0]` to get the file name.

Comment: @lord63.j thanks for the suggestion, updated my answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [3]y1=[elem[1].strip('dir').split('.')[0] for elem in y]
In [4]: res=[(i,j[0]) for i in x for j in y1 if i in j ]

In [5]: res
Out[5]: 
[('04d0e11f8ceb4b128fa723181369ba1a', 31),
 ('6244dd8bfee44a61800a25d9f2e6f743', 66),
 ('662ae26640a44a37816daa6e85ef4972', 34),
 ('7d5e1f59f7984495877a059bea643954', 33)]

In [6]: [elem[1] for elem in res]
Out[6]: [31, 66, 34, 33]
```

Comment: This does not maintain the order in x

Comment: @AJW If you want to maintain the order in x, extract all ids in y and put them in a set, then iterator over x to check whether an item is in the set

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the order in x, you need to extract all ids in `y` and put them in a set, then iterator over x to check whether an item is in the set:

```
>>> x = ["d5b44796d43c4bf5a0f252aeb49738f5", "04d0e11f8ceb4b128fa723181369ba1a", "6244dd8bfee44a61800a25d9f2e6f743", "662ae26640a44a37816daa6e85ef4972", "7d5e1f59f7984495877a059bea643954"]
>>> y = [(31, u'dir/04d0e11f8ceb4b128fa723181369ba1a.mov'), (32, u'dir/d5b44796d43c4bf5a0f252aeb49738f5.pdf'), (66, u'dir/6244dd8bfee44a61800a25d9f2e6f743.jpg'), (34, u'dir/662ae26640a44a37816daa6e85ef4972.doc'), (33, u'dir/7d5e1f59f7984495877a059bea643954.ppt')]
>>> s = set()
>>> for e in y:
...     r = re.match(r'^dir/(.*)\.', e[1])
...     if r:
...             s.add(r.group(1))
>>> [e for e in x if e in s]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ["d5b44796d43c4bf5a0f252aeb49738f5", "04d0e11f8ceb4b128fa723181369ba1a", "6244dd8bfee44a61800a25d9f2e6f743", "662ae26640a44a37816daa6e85ef4972", "7d5e1f59f7984495877a059bea643954"]

xset = set(x)

y = [(31, u'dir/04d0e11f8ceb4b128fa723181369ba1a.mov'), (32, u'dir/d5b44796d43c4bf5a0f252aeb49738f5.pdf'), (66, u'dir/6244dd8bfee44a61800a25d9f2e6f743.jpg'), (34, u'dir/662ae26640a44a37816daa6e85ef4972.doc'), (33, u'dir/7d5e1f59f7984495877a059bea643954.ppt')]

print [num for num, path in y if path.split('/')[1].split('.')[0] in xset]
```

Comment: the problem is that the order of `x` seems to be destroyed by this approach - is there any way to maintain the order of `x`?

Comment: Probably don't use a set then, a list instead. It will be a slower look up in the `in x` bit.

Comment: I was using one in my answer.

Comment: @AJW check my answer for an ordered set example

Answer (score 0):

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30438085/4890577): use `[:-4]` may not be a good idea, what if we have a `dir/04d0e11f8ceb4b128fa723181369ba1a.rmvb`? I'd suggest using `os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(thefilepath))[0]` to get the file name.

so my idea is: we map the element to the id first, `yy` should be:

```
{u'7d5e1f59f7984495877a059bea643954': 33,u'6244dd8bfee44a61800a25d9f2e6f743': 66, u'662ae26640a44a37816daa6e85ef4972': 34, u'04d0e11f8ceb4b128fa723181369ba1a': 31, u'd5b44796d43c4bf5a0f252aeb49738f5': 32}
```

and the we get the id using `yy[element]`, and the order should be as before.

---

The solution:

```
from os import path

yy = {path.splitext(path.basename(j))[0]:i for (i, j) in y}
xx = [yy[i] for i in x]
print(xx)

# output
[32, 31, 66, 34, 33]
```